# Simple PHP Form that Validates and Display Issues after Submitting or Post to Another Page if No Validation Issues

Tags: php, forms, validation, redirect

I am new to PHP coding, and am struggling to get an answer.

I need a simple php file for collecting and validating 3 variables:
(1) Reference Number (Text) (Required)
(2) Amount (Decimal) (Required)
(3) E-Mail (Text) (Required)
(4) Accept Terms and Conditions (Checkbox) (Required - Must be on)

The fields should be validated upond pressing the Submit button. If there's any validation issues it needs to stay on the same form and point out the fields that cannot be validated / reasons. If however the fields are in order and all are entered, after pressing the submit button, the values should be posted in another form.

If anyone can help or give me advice?

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried and we can then assist.

Comment: The answers to all your demands can be found researching, trial & error (*some blood, sweat & tears*), tutorials, Q&A's here on SO, etc. If that is too much work and you want it right away as 75% of the population does, hire a developer; call it "tough love" ;-)

Comment: Javascript form validation sample scripts are available here, http://www.htmldrive.net/search?q=validation&yt0.x=0&yt0.y=0&yt0=submit

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript form validation or ajax, both can be incorporated into php code. To send value from one page to another php provides GET and POST methods.

Comment: Do you have any examples I can use to check this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue.  I would like to know about this as well.  All of these down votes are not required.

I think `htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])` is one of the tools to do this.  I am not sure as I am new as well.  I am trying to use that and `isset($_POST['fname'])` in the value field that doesn't seem to work either.